# How to write a graphql fragment for contenful generic RichText

Tags: graphql, contentful

contentful automatically creates a schema based on the content of the backend.
So if I have two entries `A` and `B` with both a richtext field it will create something like this:

```
type A {
  text: AText
}

type B {
  text: BText
}

type AText {
  json: JSON!,
  links: ATextLinks!
}
type BText {
  json: JSON!,
  links: BTextLinks!
}
```

In my case `AText` and `BText` are the same so I try to create a fragment like this

```
union GenericText = AText | BText
fragment on GenericText {
  json
}
```

but it does not know that the types overlap and throws an error.
If I don't use fragments but create the query via simple string interpolation
the "fragement" works fine for all RichText types.

Can I somehow declare a interface to which all theses rich text types conform on the client?